# Apachectl Mac-Sierra 10.12.5 mod_rewrite

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The scenario:

## System version

- System Version: macOS 10.12.5
- Kernel Version: Darwin 16.6.0

## Apache version

- Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix)
- Server built:   Feb  6 2017 20:02:10

## php version;

- PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Feb  7 2017 16:18:37)
- Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
- Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

## httpd.conf, rewrite_module and php5_module are included;

- LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
- LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

## .htaccess;

- Options -Indexes
- RewriteEngine On

## /apache2/error_log;

framework/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

So, running phpinfo(), the mod_rewrite are not included, and when i cat the mod_rewrite file, cat /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so, the file exists. Anybody alredy had this problem? And Know how can i fix this?

Comment: did you use `Homebrew` to build apache and php ?

Comment: So, i fixed the problem, in the firs senario i has changed the documentRoot in a extra conf file (/etc/apache2/users/myuser.conf), and aparently the problem was here. then i changed documentRoot in httpd.conf (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf), and every thing started works just fine. But the main question is, why the extra conf doesn`t work?